# How to restore the transactions details when i reinstall the application

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

i am doing one application.In that i am using auto renewal subscription.So everything is fine now.But i have to know one more thing.When i uninstall the application from device and again install on same device,on that time how to continue my subscription.

Comment: Do you want to delete and then install or you want to update that ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to update application, you can use the following :

   Just don't delete the database once application is installed.
2. If you want to delete and re-install application, you can use the following :

   See the following question : [ios restore data after reinstalling app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386423/ios-restore-data-after-reinstalling-app)

Comment: In that link they said use KeychainItemWrapper class for restore the app data.Is it gives the database info also?

Comment: Do you want to delete app and install app or upgrade it ?

Comment: I want to reinstall the same app.Not updated version.

Comment: OK...You can use iCloud for that then to store database

Comment: But how can we store the local db data in icloud.If user not enable the icloud,What we have to do?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesignForCoreDataIniCloud.html